# `:expr` is followed by `:tt`, which is not allowed for `expr` fragments

Tags: macros, rust

I am trying to write macro that support a simple grammar like:

```
boo: 3 and foo: go or bar: 4+2
```

This is what I have tried:

```
macro_rules! solr {
    ($TOPIC:ident : $VALUE:expr $($rest:tt)*) => {
        println!("{} {}", stringify!($TOPIC), stringify!($VALUE));
    }
}

fn main() {
    solr!(
        boo: "hola!"
    );
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e30f2841d4f841bb0db25c314c475509&version=stable)

I'm receiving this error:

```
error: `$VALUE:expr` is followed by `$rest:tt`, which is not allowed for `expr` fragments
 --> src/main.rs:2:35
  |
2 |     ($TOPIC:ident : $VALUE:expr $($rest:tt)*) => {
  |                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

It makes sense, but I need to be able to accept an expression and pass the rest of the sentence to the macro again to fulfill the given sentence.

How can I support that grammar or alter the macro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I support that grammar or alter the macro?

You can't.  There is no workaround.  There is no trick.  The macro system is specifically written to *prevent* you from doing this.  The problem is that allowing arbitrary tokens after an expression (or a type, among other things) effectively prevents the Rust developers from *ever* expanding the language grammar whilst retaining backward compatibility.  Thus, it is forbidden.

You can either change the input grammar to have an acceptable terminating token *after* the expressions (such as `,` or `;`), or change to procedural macros (and redefine the macro invocation as a `#[derive]` attribute on an item).